# Controlling Multiple analog RGB 12V led strips

Tags: i2c, led, pwm

I need to control several (5 to 10) analog RGB strips which have a separate power supply at 12V or 24V. Just like [this one](http://www.adafruit.com/products/285) for example.  I need to control the intensity of each colour channel for each strip. The producer says to use any NPN or N-channel MOSFET; I think that a PWM signal per each color per each strip will be necessary to drive the mosfets.

I have tried to find a system that will allow me the least load on the raspberrypi processor (so it can process inputs with no delay) and an easy implementation, and found that I could:

- Build my own extension board using `PWM` output with mosfets, and using a software library (*pi-blaster*) to generate extra `PWM`; apparently too heavy on the processor and not enough `GPIO` pins;
- Use the leading standard DMX (expensive parts and unnecessary complication?)
- Use an `I2C` i/o expander (**MCP23017** ?);

The latter seems most appealing,  which solution would be best and easiest? I welcome pre-soldered kits / external controllers but I just want to know which way to go, I just want to dive into the software part of this project .... but I want to start with the right technology.

I'm a noob in electronics, if some of this doesn't make sense please comment to help me get the question straight.

**Update**

Here is the hardware I ended up choosing, for reference.

- @Gerben's suggested shield [Raspberry Pi - I2C 32 Channel PWM / Servo Board] based on PCA9685[2](http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-9685-2-lp.html)
- Transistor MOSFET STP16NF06 (1 per pin i.e. 3 per strip)
- [5m 12VDC 5050 SMD RGB 300-LED Strip Waterproof IP65](http://www.ebay.it/itm/5m-12VDC-5050-SMD-RGB-300-LED-Strip-Waterproof-/160962941594)
- a breadboard, wires, 12V - 5A power supply
- a box of Lego bricks to build a case for the prototype

Comment: If you want any help you need to tell us what the various  analog RGB strips require as input.

Comment: I don't know how describe it, something like this: http://www.adafruit.com/products/285 .

Comment: so you want us to do your research for you

Comment: @Milliways: I've been searching for two weeks, read all the led-related questions here, on raspberry forums, on youtube, on google... and I narrowed it down to the three options I mentioned in my question. Then I contacted many shops to understand the viability and I received totally different proposals (also they may be biased due to their products range); I know most will work, but I lack the basic understanding to determine which is best for my project. I'll welcome any suggestion/experience.

Comment: Your suggested product looks very well explained here: http://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips/usage just with 3 MOSFETs per strip.  So if all your strips are independent then you could have 5 straight away (with software PWM)

Comment: @francis Yes I've seen it, but 10 led strips * 3 colours > 26 GPIO on board of the raspberry, also I need to have some for input, this is why I'm looking for a controller / extender; I was hoping to find one that would provide both the mosfets and the extra ports, but if I need both components (controller + mosfets) that will be fine as well.

Comment: It sounds like two `TLC5940` would do the trick, or read the related questions on the right. I was recommended to use shift registers but they don't do the PWM for you.

Comment: `PCA9685` is an I2C equivalent of the `TLC5940`. At first glance it seems the `TLC5940` needs an external signal as a clock. So the Pi would still need to do something, even if the values don't change. But I could be wrong here.

Comment: http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-9685-2-lp.html

Comment: @Gerben that's it: http://www.adafruit.com/products/815 seems just perfect. I'm glad you pointed out the advantage over TLC5940. Is the MCP23017 similar but with no external power?

Comment: @Gerben also the pridopia product is so much easier than the adafruit, no wiring, definitely a winner. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it and upvote. Thank you.

Comment: Just note that you'd still need the mosfets as the PCA9685 can only sink about 25mA, and because the led strip is 12V instead of 3.3V/5V. The adafruit board already has the needed pull-up resistors on the board, which is handy. But you can't re-use the power line. The MCP23017 doesn't do PWM, so I don't see the similarities.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer a ready-made solution, **Gerben's** suggestion in a comment to use a `PCA9685` is an excellent. Apparently, Adafruit offers an affordable [PCA9685 breakout board](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2013/03/29/powering-an-analog-rgb-led-strip-with-the-pi-piday-raspberrypi-raspberry_pi/).

Alternatively, an Arduino (or just an ATMega8), which you could control from the Raspberry via SPI or I2C, might be used to generate the PWM signals and drive the MOSFETs.

---

EDIT: **Gerben** made a good point that 1 Arduino alone is not able to generate the number (5-10 or more) of independent PWM signals in hardware and that it's therefore necessary to implement that in software.

I realize that this is not [arduino.stackexchange.com](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2013/03/29/powering-an-analog-rgb-led-strip-with-the-pi-piday-raspberrypi-raspberry_pi/), but it might be worth mentioning that [ShiftPWM](http://www.elcojacobs.com/shiftpwm/), using an Arduino and a bunch of 74HC595 shift registers might do the job once the MOSFETs are added.

Comment: Arduino's don't have enough PWM pins, so you'd have to do software PWM, making it even a bit more difficult.

Comment: This PCA9685 board: https://www.adafruit.com/product/815 can be used to drive 16 MOSFETs with PWM, is chainable and controlled with simple I2C commands. Can also drive servos and steppers. https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver?view=all